# How do I say “my favourite person” in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese

My favourite... 
Pls also provide jyutping

Comment: please show some effort before asking for help

Answer (score 1):

"My **favourite** person" = "我**最喜愛嘅**人" /ngo5 zeoi3 hei2 oi3 ge3 jan4/

"My **favourite** toy" = "我**最喜愛嘅**玩具"

"My **favourite** movies star" = "我**最喜愛嘅**明星"

"My **favourite** hobby" = "我**最喜愛嘅**嚐好"

"My **favourite** son" = "我最喜愛嘅仔/ 我**最寵愛嘅**仔"

*You can use either 喜愛 or 寵愛 if you have authority over the subject (human only).*

*Example: 女兒 (daughter), 部下(subordinate), 妃嬪 (concubine), 學生 (pupil)...*

*You can say: "我**最喜愛嘅**玩具" but not: "我**最寵愛嘅**玩具"*

Answer (score 0):

我最鐘意嘅(人)
ngo5 zeoi3 zung1 ji3 ge3 (jan4)

Comment: 鐘意 in Cantonese often means "love"

Comment: True for people, but it also works for 我最鐘意嘅玩具/明星/嗜好